# Bulk Upload Image Alt Text

Tags: images, seo

I have a Google Sheet/Excel doc with unique Image Alt text for all of the images on my site. I'm looking for a way to bulk upload those, either using a plug-in, or through phpmyadmin.

Any help or advice that can be offered, is sincerely appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Hi Mike, how did you fix this?

Answer (score 2):

*TRY THIS,IT MAY HELPFUL*

1. Converted to CSV file.
2. uploaded to root folder having column structure as given which contains attachment **image ID** and **alter text**

[image: CSV upload to your root folder]

[image: my type of csv file]

3. **run this code for one time only**

```
$row    = 1;
if( ($handle = fopen ( "Book1.csv", "r" )) !== FALSE ) {
    while ( ($data = fgetcsv ( $handle, 1000, "," )) !== FALSE ) {
        $image_id       = $data[ 0 ];
        $image_alt_text = $data[ 1 ];
        update_post_meta ( (int) $image_id, '_wp_attachment_image_alt', $image_alt_text );
    }
    fclose ( $handle );
}
```

Comment: Hi Kirtan, is this solution better than using a plugin/WordPress webhook? My requirement is "There are 890+ unique images that are located in the Media Library that we can add ALT text to that should populate the page"